# Buttons with :after not working with event handler in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some buttons with event handlers in JS. When I use :after in the CSS (for aesthetic reasons), the buttons no longer work. It seems to work in codepen, but not in my project and not in this minimum reproducible code as I've copied here:

Any idea on how I can get the buttons working and keep the :after? The :after is so that the box shadow does not overlap on the adjacent buttons

```js
document.getElementById('1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert("hit");
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #dedede;
}

.buttonFirst {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 4em;
  padding-top: 10%;
  color: #000;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 2vw;
  outline: 2px;
  border: 2px;
  border-style: none;
}

.buttonFirst:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 2vw;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonFirst" id="1"></button>
<button class="buttonFirst" id="2"></button>
<button class="buttonFirst" id="3"></button>
<button class="buttonFirst" id="4"></button>
```

Comment: The reason why it's not working in this snippet is because of the incorrectly closed script tag at the bottom of the file (`<script src="main.js"</script>`). Fix that and the code snippet will work. Check your syntax in other environments you're experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Ah, you're right about that, that explains that! But it still doesn't work in my project with the proper closed tag

Comment: What's different about your project that isn't replicated in CodePen or the code snippet above? Are you outputting your external script tag to `main.js` in the same place below the html buttons?

Comment: Yep, it's right at the bottom just before the closing body tag. The buttons have all been working fine for the past few weeks, this morning I decided to add box shadow, and if I add :after to avoid overlap of the shadow, it breaks them. Have spent all day looking through and I can't find any reason why it should affect it

Comment: Are your click events still working if you remove all other styles form the pseudo element `:after` and just keep the `content` property (to keep it active)?

Comment: No, it doesn't even work if I remove the entire :after { ... } (what do you call these, functions?) -- the only way I can get it to work is if I add a higher z-index to the main button css, but that means the overlap of the box shadow comes back

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214450/discussion-between-uncaughttypeerror-and-joseph).

Comment: For anyone who has this problem in the future: @UncaughtTypeError fixed my problem -- I had another element with a higher z-index that was hidden using 'opacity:0'. I now know I should hide elements with display:none rather than by changing opacity. Thank you!